# Cannot save stream as image

Tags: c#, mime-types, multipartform-data, multipart

I am trying to get an image from multipart-mixed content, I can get the stream but am so far unable to convert it into the image.  The error I am getting is :

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred 
    in System.Drawing.dll

    Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

Here is the relevant code up to the line where it fails:

```
Image img;

using (var stream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\in_mms.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var content2 = new StreamContent(stream) ;
            content2.Headers.ContentType = 
                System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse (
                    "multipart/related; boundary=cbsms-main-boundary");

            var multipart = await content2.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

            foreach (StreamContent part in multipart.Contents)
            {
                if (part.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "multipart/mixed")
                {
                    Stream y = await part.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    y.Position = 0;

                    if (part.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                        await part.ReadAsMultipartAsync(StreamProvider);

                    foreach (var mixedContent in StreamProvider.Contents)
                    {
                        if (mixedContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "image/jpeg"
                        || mixedContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "image/png"
                        || mixedContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "image/gif")
                        {
                            //save image
                            Stream x = await mixedContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                            x.Position = 0;
                            img = Image.FromStream(x);
```

And is the text file I am trying to obtain the image from :

```
    Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 5216
Content-Type: multipart/related;
     boundary="cbsms-main-boundary";
     start="<soap-envelope>", text/xml;
     charset=utf-8
Accept: */*
Host: hostname
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)
soapaction: ""

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--cbsms-main-boundary
Content-Type: text/xml;
     charset="utf-8"
Content-ID: <soap-envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<mm7:TransactionID
xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL
-6-MM7-1-2">5947CCE35D5B4AEFB99DADDDF9472E67</mm7:TransactionID>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<mm7:DeliverReq
xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL
-6-MM7-1-2">
<mm7:MM7Version>6.5.0</mm7:MM7Version>
<mm7:MMSRelayServerID>hostname</mm7:MMSRelayServerID>
<mm7:LinkedID>1-1754394156</mm7:LinkedID>
<mm7:SenderAddress>
<mm7:Number>46707630767</mm7:Number>
</mm7:SenderAddress>
<mm7:Recipients>
<mm7:To>
<mm7:Number>72401</mm7:Number>
</mm7:To>
</mm7:Recipients>
<mm7:TimeStamp>2008-05-08 11:16:39</mm7:TimeStamp> <mm7:Priority>Normal</mm7:Priority>
<mm7:Subject>Tube test</mm7:Subject>
</mm7:DeliverReq>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

--cbsms-main-boundary
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
     boundary="cbsms-sub-boundary"
Content-ID: <MM7-Media>

--cbsms-sub-boundary
content-type: application/smil;
    Name=main.smil;Charset=utf-8
content-transfer-encoding: 7bit
content-id: <AAAA>
content-length: 483

<smil><head><layout><root-layout backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
background-color="#FFFFFF" height="480px" width="640px"/> <region id="Image" top="0" left="0" height="50%" width="100%" fit="meet"/> <region id="Text" top="50%" left="0" height="50%" width="100%"
fit="scroll"/>
</layout>
</head>
<body><par dur="4000ms"><img src="smslogo.jpg" region="Image"></img> <text src="smil.txt" region="Text"><param name="foreground-color"
value="#000000"/>
</text>
</par>
</body>
</smil>

--cbsms-sub-boundary
content-type: image/jpeg;
    Name=smslogo.jpg
content-transfer-encoding: Base64
content-location: smslogo.jpg
content-length: 2218
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--cbsms-sub-boundary
content-type: text/plain;
    Name=smil.txt;Charset=utf-8
content-transfer-encoding: 7bit
content-location: smil.txt
content-length: 9

Tube test
--cbsms-sub-boundary--

--cbsms-main-boundary--
```

And when I step through the code I get the following Header value :

```
{content-type: image/jpeg; Name=smslogo.jpg
content-transfer-encoding: Base64
content-location: smslogo.jpg
content-length: 2218
}
```

EDIT :

I try to save the image like this :

```
 img.Save(@"C:\temp\filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But I get the error :

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

I can confirm that the image is a valid image as I was able to extract it using a 3rd party component.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: Added more code prior to the point where it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a base 64 encoded image. Get this part of the text as string:

```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```

That is the actual image encoded. Try this:

```
byte[] base64Bytes = await mixedContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
string base64String = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(base64Bytes);
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: How would I extract just that part of the text?

Comment: Edited the answer, to get the bytes instead of the stream.

Comment: Hi, I can now get the image to load from the stream, but the image does not save (see edit above)

Comment: Can't figure it out why, the only thing I can think of by now is that the image is not JPG, but another image format. Try to save the stream in a file, and check the file with ImageMagick or any other image software, to find the right format.